# How to transform from SQL Server text field to xml and back

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, xml, linq-to-xml

We save our xml in a SQL Server database with the data type text, so it's a long string.

What I now need to do is transform this string to xml, and then work with this and finally transform it back to a string to be saved back to the database.

The xml:

```
<Posts>
    <DialogPost>
      <Type></Type>
      <User></User>
      <Customer></Customer>
      <Date></Date>
      <Message></Message>
    </DialogPost>
</Posts>
```

I've started working with Linq to xml, and it seems to be great but I'm having problem making it work.

```
XDocument dialogXML = XDocument.Load("trying to load the xml string right in");
```

It doesn't like the string straight from the db.  How would you recommend me to tackle this problem? Both reading and writing back to the db.

Comment: Why not store it in an XML field to begin with?

Comment: I'm depending on another application that that already is saving it to this text field, absolutely prefered a xml field type.

Comment: I corrected the XML you posted. If that wasn't a typo, then please revert my change, restoring the invalid XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `XDocument.Parse` method.  `Load` expects a URI not XML.

You should also note that the XML you posted is not valid.  You have a closing `Dialog` tag at the end but no opening tag.  Here is an example that would work with valid XML.

```
string str =
@"<?xml version=""1.0""?>
<!-- comment at the root level -->
<Posts>
    <DialogPost>
      <Type></Type>
      <User></User>
      <Customer></Customer>
      <Date></Date>
      <Message></Message>
    </DialogPost>
  </Posts>";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(str);
```

[Take a look here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.parse.aspx) for an example and more info.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks. And if I'd like to add more <DialogPost> how do I prefably do that?

Comment: You would just add another `DialogPost` below the closing `DialogPost` tag but before the closing `Posts` tag.